# In Excel how do i find the cell reference of the min value in a named range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a named range : mycosts comprised of these cells: 
 $D$20,$D$31,$D$42,$D$50

The cells contain numbers.  I need the min and max numbers in the range.  I know how to do that with the min and max functions.  What I need to know is the cell reference, or just the row, of the cell that had the min value in it and the max value.  I need this so that I can reference antoher cell in ColA from that row number.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can probably use INDEX/MATCH. What are you doing with the cell in column A?

Comment: Next time please explain what you have tried or what you think might work but without any luck figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the disjoint nature of the range, I would use a VBA UDF:

```
Public Function WhereIsMin(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim vlu As Double, r As Range
    vlu = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
    For Each r In rng
            If r.Value = vlu Then
                WhereIsMin = r.Row
                Exit Function
            End If
    Next r
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given that all your cost figures are sitting in `Column D`, you can use **MATCH** to return the **row number** using the following formula:

```
=MATCH(MIN(mycosts),D1:D50,0)
```

> You may use absolute reference for the range in Column D such as `$D$1:$D$50` given that you may use this formula within another formula.

If you have other numerical values in that range which could be the same as the minimum cost (hence returning an incorrect row number), you may use a **helper column** to "exclude" other numerical values. As shown in the following example, the second formula returned `19` as the row number for the minimum cost but the correct answer should be `20` as returned by the first formula.

[image: Example]

```
{=MATCH(MIN(mycosts),IF(LEFT($C$1:$C$50,4)="Cost",$D$1:$D$50,""),0)}
```

Please note it is an **array formula** which needs to be confirmed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the formula bar.

In the above example I used the word `Cost` in `Column C` to identify the relevant figures in `Column D`, and then do the **MATCH** within the filtered range. You may use other methods to filter the range in Column D depending on your actual data.

Let me know if you have any question. Cheers :)